# Setup JUnit for this specific project in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit4

I'm trying to set up JUnit4 for this project, with tests already provided.
However the java files seems strange, and it doesn’t let me add JUnit to classpath.

[image]

Beginner here and totally don’t know what happened:(

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run the "production" class `Q1Ceil` instead of its test, `Q1CeilTest`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the **tests** directory set as a **Test Source Root** directory [category](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories). You can mark it form the directory context menu in Project tool window:
[image]

See also [Configure folder categories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#project_tool_window) official documentation for the steps.